# Udacity: Functional Hardware Verification. What are the implementations?

Tags: embedded, hardware, verification

I've just finished watching the first week of Functional Hardware Verification course at Udacity. In the promo, it says, it requires both Electrical Engineer and Software Engineer skills. This is why it intrigued me. But I got an impression like, it is only for chip designers. Am I wrong?
Can it be also useful for embedded software developing ?
For example, how can I utilize this information with a Raspberry Pi and/or an Android device ? Is it possible or am I wasting my time with this course? 
I'll be happy if someone could give me an insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) is this a stack overflow question?  not sure, will see what happens.

2) is this a waste of time, I would argue no, its free, just watch, learn something

3) does it apply to embedded on a raspberry pi or android?  probably not, depends on your definition of embedded first off, if you are making api/library calls to an operating system or environment, that is just writing applications.  if you are digging down into the bare metal, it gets closer, but not quite.  Now if you are working somewhere where you work hand in hand or are or are going to be designing chips, fpgas, cplds, etc.  And, the company is such that they are willing to move into the 1990's or 2000's and allow the software developers to develop against the rtl in simulation, access to the simulator licenses (very expensive, doesnt take very many cadence licences to shadow your salary).

During the chip development phase of time (vs the post silicon sell the chips for a while before the next chip starts) we build our own sims using the kinds of things I assume this class is teaching, but perhaps not since the traditional testing methods are not quite what I am talking about.  we sim portions or the whole chip, use the "foreign language interface" or whatever the vendor calls it, to interface software to the simulated hardware.  We do it using an abstraction layer in such a way that a high percentage of the code we write against sim will run against silicon using a different abstraction layer/shim.  This can give months to a year or more head start on the software, and can find bugs in the logic design as well as the design of the hardware/software interface (are interrupts a good idea, can we poll fast enough, use dma, etc).

Cadence is of course going to push their product and their ways of doing things even though their products support a wide range of features.  There are other tools.  I am a fan of verilator, open source, free.  but it is very particular about the verilog it supports, mostly synthesizable only, and that is fine by me, so depending on the verilog author you are relying on they may not have habits that support whate verilator is looking for.  icarus verilog is much more forgiving but very slow.  verilator is like 10 times slower than cadence, icarus is slower than that.  but free is free...There are a number of things at opencores for example that you can play with if you want to see this in action, amber, mpx, and altor32 are ones I have played with for example.

If you land one of these chip/board company jobs then familiarity with simulators like cadence and modelsim and the free tools (verilator, icarus, gtkwave, ghdl, etc) are valuable.  Being able to read verlog and/or vhdl (which is not hard if you are already a programmer, the only thing new is that some of the code is truly "parallel", which with multi-core processors today that is not actually a new thing for a programmer).  If you are able to interface software to the simulator, then you are an asset to that company because you can facilitate this development against the simulated hardware and save the company money in units of multiples of your salary with found bugs before silicon and shorting the schedule by many months.

Lastly, being able to look at waveforms and see your code execute is an addictive experience.

Just like learning bare metal, or assembly, getting familiar with hardware at this next lower level can only help you as a programmer, even if the experience is with logic or processors that are not the ones you are programming.  Remember that just like programmers, take any N number of programmers given the same task they may come up with anywhere up to N different solutions.  Just because one implementation of a mips clone has certain details does not mean all mips nor all processors look like that on the insides.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that is really helpful. I am new to StackOverflow, I'll be happy to learn which platform fits better to this type of question.